# How to display multiple user's status in single page?

Tags: php, laravel

I am making a discussion forum. I need to display all user's post on home page of every user. If user has signed in all the post made by all users should be displayed. This is my code in Home controller and this is displaying only one user record from table.

```
$Statuses = Status::where(function($query){
                return $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->lists('id');
        })->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$Statuses = Status::where(function($query){
            return (Auth::check()) ? $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id) : $query;
        })->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(10);
```

You got the idea and you can easily modify query for your needs.

`paginate(10)` should grab all users' statuses if `Auth::check()` will return `false`. Otherwise, query will grab only current user's statuses.

Answer (score 0):

take the returned query and run it through a while loop.

```
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCHASSOC)){echo row['yourColumnName'];}
```